# Cut Linux variable number of spaces

Tags: linux, space, cut

I need to get in linux the third column...

I used first **last | cut -d " " -f 3** but it doesn't work and after that I taught the char is a TAB and used **last | cut -f 2**
and it's still not working...

how shoult i get that?

[image]

Comment: Note that some entries might contain spaces (e.g. `reboot  system boot  4.1.36-44-default Wed Jan 11...`)

Answer (score 0):

You might try it with `awk`:

```
<your-program-giving-tabular-output> | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

For example with `ps`:

```
ps | awk '{ print $3 }'
```